# How to verify that the entered data is present in the database in laravel

Tags: request, laravel-8

How to verify that the entered data is present in the database, if it does not exist, it will be returned with an error message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use findOrFail($id). doc : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions